# LibGDX Android Textures reload other textures, and transparent images get black backgrounds [Pictures]

Tags: android, libgdx, textures

I have very strange problems with my LibGDX Game in Android - The problem is that sometimes the textures get black backgrounds when they should be transparent, and sometimes when I remove the texture, or press the back button, the textures get replaced with other textures that I have.

**To clarify:**
I'm using x texture to show the status of health. I'm using three x textures to show how many lives the player got, and when I lose health, and remove one texture, the x texture get replaced with y or z texture, or the remaining x textures get black backgrounds. Sometimes it works flawlessly, and the x texture gets removed, and the backgrounds are still transparent.

I'm loading my textures via an AssetManager, and just load them on create().

**In my render I use this:**

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    batch.enableBlending();

                  batch.begin();
                   for (Entity life : LifeEntities) {

                        life.render(batch);
                    }
                  batch.end();
```

**I'm also using this in my Launcher Class.**

```
 AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
 cfg.r = cfg.g = cfg.b = cfg.a = 8;

 MainGame myGame = new MainGame(arrayName);
 initialize(myGame, cfg);
```

I do dispose the textures also. I have looked up on google and on gamedev about this problem, but all the questions are for problems when the transparent always have black background, not when it is something that happens like a bug.

Any suggestions on where the problem could be? Thanks a lot, if you need more code, please let me know.

**Pictures of the problem:**
[image: Black Backgrounds]

[image: Messed up textures]

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with your framework nor your target platform but, could it be that when you load a texture more than once, it's the same that is used (data sharing), but when you remove it, the manager is not aware that it is shared so the other instances get garbage?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Thank you for your input. I will try to add a picture. Thank you for suggesting it. No, I don't think that's how it works, because even when I only use one texture of it, I still get the same problem.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I added the pictures now, is it more clear what the problem is? Thanks for the advice once again.

Comment: It is, unfortunately, this is beyond my domain of expertise; you'll probably have better input from other users!